# 'PROJ: proj_create_from_database: Cannot find proj.db' error when trying to load tif image

Tags: python, conda, raster, rasterio

Trying to open a tif file using rasterio using the following code:

```
import rasterio
from rasterio.plot import show
fp = r'L7-L5_fused2020.tif'
img = rasterio.open(fp)
show(img)
```

However, I am getting the following error:

{Sorry for the link...not enough reputation points :/ }

[image: Error]

Can someone explain how to rectify this 'Cannot find proj.db' error? I am using rasterio version 1.2.10 and conda version 23.7.2

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.